# can't open (to install) apk built from android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I cant open APK that I built from android studio `build > Generate Signed APK`.  the build went smooth without error but I could not open the APK to install it.

FYI I already tried another APK from somewhere and I could open it, so it's not my phone issue or security.

how to fix this? I am lost because there is no error. it just says `can't open file`.

this is my gradle

```
     apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

     apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

     apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

     android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mockie.daikokuten"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    }

     dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sqlite:0.10.3"
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.0.0"
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation files('libs/tscsdk.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: any error log ? when you try to open installed apk ?

Comment: no. it only says `APK(s) generated successfully`

Comment: @Lucifer I just added my gradle in my question. please take a look

Comment: try Aditya's answer

Comment: have you tried installing from the command line with `adb install`?

Comment: adb install works! But I still can't install manually :( I'm pretty new to android. I want to share my apk without publishing to the play store or asking users to build manually.

Comment: Okay...I got it to work using `adb -d push /path/to/apk /path/on/device`. But I'd still like to know why manually copying the apk does not work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create you *Signed APK* with below process.

- `Build` > Generate `Signed` apk.
- Create `Keystore` path.
- Put `Password, alias,` key `password`.
- Build type (`Release` for `Play Store`).
- Signature Version select `V1` and `V2` both checkboxes inside this.
- `Finish`

Update

Also you may need to check that if an app is already installed with same `package name`. Go to Settings ==> Apps ==> Click on your App ==> In App info page at the action bar menu there will be an option called `Uninstall for All users` click that.

Comment: i did check both of them but i cant still open the apk.

Comment: is release version only open-able from google play? because i dont put in there.

Comment: @Kakashi No you can install release build even on your device not necessary to install it from *Play Store*. Make sure when you create *release signed apk* you should copy it to any of the *internal storage* folder and then try to install it.

Comment: @Kakashi Mark it as accepted and upvote if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing kind of the same issue with an Ionic 4 build Android app.

Once I built my app and got an apk, I open it with Android Studio then in menu I choose

```
Build > Build Bundle(s) / APK(s) > Build APK(s)
```

so I can install my apk on my device when I open the generated apk from Archive

Answer (score 0):

Follow this article  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/manually-signing-the-apk

I had the same issue and the solution was to sign the apk by yourself. Generally, the IDE is responsible of this operation but sometimes it doesn't do the job.