# Cannot open apk after install

Tags: java, android-studio, apk

I developed an android studio application with custom chrome tab for my website.

```
public class AnnaStudio {
    String url = "https://www.example.com/";
    CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
    CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();
    customTabsIntent.launchUrl(this, Uri.parse(url));

}
```

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

[image: Cannot run the app after install]

I tried building both as debug and as a signed release.

I followed [can't open (to install) apk built from android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49629821/cant-open-to-install-apk-built-from-android-studio) But it seems to address other issue, and the solutions weren't good for me.

Answer (score 0):

If i am getting it right, you transported the .apk file to your phone and tried to open it there. First of all, you need an android phone. There you navigate to the play store and download the "APK Installer" app. Open this app and install your .apk file like instructed there, hope i could help.

Comment: Still doesn't work. And why do I need a 'apk installer'?

Comment: Worked for me when i tried with my apps. Can you explain the steps you are making from start to the end ? At best, you post your code and your config files.